# YUI chart with multiple series

Tags: javascript, charts, yui, yui-charts

I'm looking to create a chart with

- days on the x-axis (any number from 1 to 30)
- 24 hours on the y-axis
- three series plotted into the chart at a date/time coordinate

I have one problem left.
One series keep getting double axis labels.

```
var myAxes = {
            dateRange: {
                calculateEdgeOffset: true,
                keys: ["date"],
                position: "bottom",
                type: "time",
                labelFormat: "%e %b %Y",
                styles: {
                    majorTicks: { display: "none" },
                    label: { rotation: -65, margin: { top: 5 } },
                    marker: { shape: "rect" },
                    line: { weight: 0 }
                }
            },
            timestamp: {
                keys: ["minutes"],
                position: "left",
                labelFunction: function (val) {
                    var display = padLeft(Math.floor(val / 60), 2, "0");
                    display += ":" + padLeft((val % 60), 2, "0");
                    return display;
                }
            }
        };
```

The "dateRange" is good, but the "timestamp" keeps getting my own "labelFunction"-overridden values on the left AND auto-generated values on the right.

Working example code: http://jsfiddle.net/madmital/Nqa6R/

Comment: I'd remove the part of the question which you have solved and make it clearer what you are really asking. Removing the "minutes" series or something something labels?

Comment: Right you are. I updated the question, hopefully narrowing it down. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up leaving YUI charts and going with Google Charts instead - https://developers.google.com/chart/ - which for me is a lot easier to work with.